# In a Gulp task, how can I set a variable value in the first pipe and read it in the second pipe?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a task with two piped statements. The second pipe relies on a global variable whose value is declared in the first pipe. But, I am not able to access the global variable from the second pipe. It seems like pipe 2 is starting before pipe 1 finishes.

```js
var responsive = require('gulp-responsive');
var tap = require('gulp-tap');

// global variables for image-generator task
var imageA1Width = 0;
var imageA1Height = 0;

// extracts width and height from image path
function getDimensionsFromPath(path) {
    // example image: banner-fooBar-$a1-1000x901.jpg
    var path = path || '';
    var dimensionsString = '';
    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;
    var re = /[^-]*$/;
    dimensionsString = path.match(re)[0];
    dimensionsString = dimensionsString.replace('.jpg', '');
    dimensionsString = dimensionsString.replace('.png', '');
    dimensionsString = dimensionsString.replace('.webp', '');
    dimensionsString = dimensionsString.replace('.gif', '');
    var dimensionsArr = dimensionsString.split('x');
    width = parseInt(dimensionsArr[0], 10);
    height = parseInt(dimensionsArr[1], 10);
    var obj = {
        width: width,
        height: height
    };
    return obj;
}

gulp.task('image-generator', function () {
    var imageKeyPattern = /-\$a1.*$/; // example image: banner-fooBar-$a1-1000x901.jpg
    return gulp.src('images/**/*$a1*.*')
        .pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
            var imageA1Path = file.path;
            // global variables
            imageA1Width = getDimensionsFromPath(imageA1Path).width;
            imageA1Height = getDimensionsFromPath(imageA1Path).height;
        }))
        .pipe(responsive({
            '**/*$a1*.*': [{
                width: imageA1Width * 2, // NaN
                skipOnEnlargement: true,
                rename: function (opt) {
                    opt.basename = opt.basename.replace(imageKeyPattern, '-extralarge@2x');
                    opt.dirname = '';
                    return opt;
                }
            },
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('imagesGenerated/'));
});
```

Comment: There's no way to answer this question without an  [actual working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes what `secondThing` is.

Comment: Good suggestion Sven Schoenung, I added an actual working example that includes the secondThing (gulp-responsive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

You compute the value for the `imageA1Width` var in the `tap()` pipeline stage meaning the var is reset for **every** file moving through the stream.

However `imageA1Width` is evaluated only **once** (as part of the object literal that gets passed to `responsive()`) and before the stream has even been created. At that time `imageA1Width` is still undefined.

**Solution:**

What we need to do is compute a different width value for each `file` in the stream. Then for each `file` we need to call `responsive()` individually since each `file` will have a different width. We can do this using [`gulp-foreach`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foreach):

```
var foreach = require('gulp-foreach');

gulp.task('image-generator', function () {
  var imageKeyPattern = /-\$a1.*$/;
  return gulp.src('images/**/*$a1*.*')
    .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file) {
       var size = getDimensionsFromPath(file.path);
       return stream
        .pipe(responsive({
           '**/*$a1*.*': [{
             width: size.width * 2,
             skipOnEnlargement: true,
             rename: function (opt) {
               opt.basename = opt.basename.replace(imageKeyPattern, 
                                                   '-extralarge@2x');
               opt.dirname = '';
               return opt;
             }
           }]
         }));
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('imagesGenerated/'));
});
```

Comment: Sven, that worked like a charm. Thanks! It seems like we can just remove gulp-tap and move the file.width and file.height variable assignments inside the foreach block. It would be nice to remove the gulp-tap dependency. If you agree, could you update your solution?

Comment: Well, duh, I could have thought of that myself. I've updated my answer. There's no need to have multiple `getDimensionsFromPath()` calls either, so I simplified that as well.

Comment: Although, it doesn't really answer the question "how to set a value in the first pipe and read it in the second?". So, just wanted to point out your solution for that: Wrap pipe 2 with gulp-foreach